# Same query ran on the same database on two servers returns different order

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query which I run on two database restores on two SQL Server 2008R2 instances and they return the results with different ordering (on one server they're ordered by ID and on the other they aren't ordered)

```
SELECT 
    C.ID AS CodeID
    , C.Format FormatId 
FROM bankCodes C
INNER JOIN bankFormat F ON (C.Format = F.ID)
```

As you can see there is no ORDER BY clause in the query, but the order the results are being displayed is different.

I have tried to rebuild the indexes for the two tables, but it didn't work.

When running a `SELECT * FROM bankCodes` on the server where the ordering of the above query is implicitly done by ID, the results are not ordered (by primary key column), but after `JOIN`ing with `bankFormat` table, the results are ordered.

I don't know what else to look for in order to explain this.

Could anyone else suggest what could be the cause of this?

***Could it be something related to database collation, indexes or primary/foreign keys?***

Comment: Yes, the cause of this is that you don't have an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY` clause the ordering of the result set in SQLServer is arbitrary as explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I know I need an `ORDER BY` for ordering, but why does an "implicit" order occur after JOIN-ing with another table?

Comment: You will *always* get the rows in *some* order. There may be indexes and lots of things impacting the "natural" order that the data is returned in, as long as you didn't specify. In any case, this is documented, if you don't add ORDER BY, the database engine is free to return the rows in any particular order it wants, including a new random one every time. To be honest, sometimes I think the random order should be implemented just to make sure people added the ORDER BY if they actually cared about the order.

Comment: The "implicit" order you get from joining is that joining uses data structures like hash tables or lists or merges or things like that. Depending on the actual data structure and algorithm, data may be returned in a particular order. If the indexes or data change, a different algorithm might be picked as the best one, and then the order changes. This is how it should be.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I understand and agree with you. But unfortunately I was tasked to offer details about why this is happening and it seems that the `we need an ORDER BY` is not sufficient.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thank you very much for your explanations. This should be enough to "get the off my back". Thanks again!

Comment: The actual reason is undocumented. Since the rule is that unless you add ORDER BY, the database engine is free to pick whatever order it wants, then it doesn't have to state why. In other words, if you want a detailed lists of what will impact the ordering, and perhaps even a detailed reason for why your data is returned in the order it was returned, you won't find it.

Comment: This article is one of my favorites on the topic. It has a working example of the results being returned in a different order. It is focused on the myth that a query will return in the order of the clustered index but the concept is exactly the same thing. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for why data is returned from the database in a particular order, when you don't add an `ORDER BY` clause contains a multitude of elements:

- Indexes
- Data
- The order the data was inserted in (which may impact the way data is stored on disk, separated into pages, etc.)

Then when querying, there's lots of other things:

- The order of the joins (both the order they were specified in and the order the database engine decides to consider/execute them)
- How the database engine decides to do joins or `WHERE` clauses, things like hash tables, hash sets, mergejoins, table lookups, etc. will impact the "natural" order the data is available in

The problem is that these reasons are not exhaustive, and will never be. The database has a "license to reorder" when you don't specify an order, and it will use it, it doesn't have to explain its actions beyond that.

As such, if you want to know the specific reason some data was returned in a particular way, you *may* look at the execution plan, but it may not tell the whole picture. This picture is also a (possibly contrived) snapshot of the current execution plan. When data or indexes changes, it may change at any time.

As such, you won't find the definitive answer here.

There is only one rule to follow:

> If you care about the order of the returned data, add `ORDER BY`

Corollary to that rule:

> If you don't add an `ORDER BY` clause, you lose all rights to care/complain about the (incorrect) order

Answer (score 2):

That is because you did not add an `order by` clause.

A DB is optimised for speed. If you specify an order the data will be delivered that way. But without it it will just grab the records in any order as fast as possible.

That is why you can't rely on any "implicit" ordering. Define one if you need it, otherwise you can't depend on anything.

Comment: I kind of knew that data on disk is not necessarily stored in a contiguous area and this is why it is possible for data to be retrieved "randomly" if you run `SELECT * FROM table`, but I wanted to make sure that there are no other possible causes.

Comment: There can be lots of possible causes for this. It could be that the data is read first time from disk and thus returned in the natural order from disk, but then is cached in a different data structure in memory for subsequent requests, and thus the next time you might get it in a slightly different order. The rule is that if you don't specify an ORDER BY, then the database engine is free to return the rows in any order it wants. Let me rewrite that. If you don't specify an ORDER BY, you lose all ability to complain that it comes in the wrong order.